# Visual studio 2010 debugging bug in sp1

Tags: c#, debugging

Are this is a bug why they occured every time in debug.

i am trying to debug my project from a time and i found that they stop on breakpoint even i remove them last time.

means when i make a breakpoint and run that's work but after debug my project next time i found that they not removed even i remove them last time when i debug.

why they not remove the breakpoint even i remove them last time on debug. are this bug if yes are their any sollution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Debug->Windows->Breakpoints and see if they are deleted.
You can not delete breakpoints while debugging the project AFAIR.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are removing break points without stopping debug:

try this stop debugging Shift+f5 and remove breakpoints

and on next run you hopefully wont find any breakpoint